# prefix to post permalinks without affecting category permas

Tags: categories, permalinks

I'm trying to make my links like this:

```
site.com/article-sample-post
```

as "article" is a fixed prefix and "sample-post" is the post slug..

but that prefix affect the category link structure making it :

```
site.com/article-category/sample-cat
```

which is not desired!

my question:
does there any simple hack or plugin so i can make working permalinks like this:

```
site.com/article-sample-post
site.com/sample-cat
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the category base `/category/`, you can install the [WP no category base plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) which will add a new set of rewrite rules for categories. the side-effect of this is that you can set your post permalinks to `/article-%postname%/` and it will no longer effect category permalinks. it will still however effect tags.

Your other option, or in conjunction with the above plugin, is to filter `post_link` to add the `article-` prefix, then modify incoming requests to remove that prefix so WordPress can find the post:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'wpa68069_post_prefix' );
function wpa68069_post_prefix( $url ) {
    $prefix = 'article-';
    $parts = explode( '/', $url );
    return home_url( '/' ) . $prefix . $parts[ count( $parts ) - 2 ] . '/';
}


add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa68069_parse_request' );
function wpa68069_parse_request( $request ){        
    if( !isset( $request->query_vars['name'] ) )
        return $request;

    if( false !== strpos( $request->query_vars['name'], 'article-' ) )
        $request->query_vars['name'] = substr( $request->query_vars['name'], 8 );

    return $request;
}
```

Comment: thx for help but,
actually none of both options work...
no category base removes the base but not the prefix! like this "site.com/article-sample-cat"....

second option broken too! it echo the links for all posts like this 

    "site.com/article-site.com"

Comment: both are tested and working with latest WordPress and TwentyEleven theme. What version are you using? What are your permalink settings?

Comment: yes you're right "no category base" working but i was using "no category parent" instead, cause i want only one cat in link addition to no base...
but the code snippet still not working and generates the above link for all posts. i'm using the latest wordpress with twentyeleven theme. posts structure "/article-%postname%.html"

Comment: ah, ok, the `post_link` function assumes your permalink settings are `/%postname%/`, you'll have to modify it to return the correct link: `return home_url( '/' ) . $prefix . $parts[ count( $parts ) -1 ];`

Comment: also- in case it' not clear, your permalink settings should not have `article-` in them, that's the whole point of the above code, it's added dynamically.

Comment: :) yes i got that , i removed the 'article-' part but the '.html' was still making conflict.
now it returns correct links but with 404 error :( ... and is it possible to add .html to links also?
thanks

Comment: it's very appreciated if you can pay more of your time to help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This simple function add `/articles` before each post link eg. `http://www.example.com/my-new-one-post/` will be change to `http://www.example.com/articles/my-new-one-post/`

I have permalink structure set to `/%postname%/`. Links like http://www.example.com/new-article

```
add_filter(
    'post_link', function ($url) {
        $parts = parse_url($url);

        if ($parts['path']) $parts['path'] = '/articles' . $parts['path'];
        $parts['scheme'] .= '://';
        if (isset($parts['query'])) $parts['query'] = '?' . $parts['query'];
        if (isset($parts['port'])) $parts['port'] = ':' . $parts['port'];
        if (isset($parts['fragment'])) $parts['fragment'] = '#' . $parts['fragment'];

        return implode('', $parts);
    }
);
```

The advantage of this solution is that preview links and short links (http://www.example.com/articles/?p=3677) also works well.